# Show hide toggle List Component AntDesign

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Is there a way I can limit the data listed in List Component in AntDesign?
I want to put hide and show toggle after 10 items listed.

This is the sample of what I'm making

[image]

Here's my code

```
  const { detailsSource } = props;

  <List
   itemLayout="horizontal"
   dataSource={detailsSource}
   header={<div>Request Details</div>}
   footer={<a onClick={toggleDetails}>More Details</a>}
   bordered
   renderItem={item => (
     <>
      <Row
       type="flex"
       style={{
         padding: '10px 24px',
         borderBottom: '1px solid #e8e8e8',
       }}
      >
        <Col span={12}>{item.label}</Col>
        <Col span={12}>{item.description}</Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show no footer until 10 items are added, you can check for a condition in your footer props. I am assuming your `detailsSource` has a length

```
footer={
   detailsSource.length > 10 
     ? <a onClick={toggleDetails}>More Details</a>
     : ""
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `loadMore` property available to the `List` component. An example in their documentation can be found here: https://ant.design/components/list/#components-list-demo-loadmore

Answer (score 0):

i think you can make a toogle by modify your detailsSource

```
const [isToggle, setIsToggle] = useState(false)
const LIMIT = 10
const data = isToggle ? detailsSource.filter((item, index) => index <= LIMIT) : detailsSource
```

then you can use data

```
  <List
   itemLayout="horizontal"
   dataSource={data}
   header={<div>Request Details</div>}
   footer={<a onClick={toggleDetails}>More Details</a>}
   bordered
   renderItem={item => (
     <>
      <Row
       type="flex"
       style={{
         padding: '10px 24px',
         borderBottom: '1px solid #e8e8e8',
       }}
      >
        <Col span={12}>{item.label}</Col>
        <Col span={12}>{item.description}</Col>
      </Row>
    </>
  )}
```

Comment: Where can I put the setIsToggle?

Comment: footer={<a onClick={setIsToggle(!isToggle )}>More Details</a>}

sorry i use reactHook in this example